# #include <boost/chrono.hpp> causes unresolved external symbol, bcp used

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, linker-errors, lnk2001

I'm not an experienced programmer.
I tried to cut part of boost and paste it directly into my project which is a C++ solution in Visual Studio 2010. 
I've done it this way:

- uncompress boost library
- `bootstrap.bat`
- `bjam tools/bcd` - this created dir *.\bin.v2\tools\bcp\msvc-10.0\release\link-static\threading-multi\*
- change dir to mentioned above
- i've written a script for scanning all files in the solution, the result is: 
  *noncopyable static_assert ratio thread/locks thread chrono interprocess/mapped_region thread/recursive_mutex crc cstdint interprocess/file_mapping make_shared shared_ptr lexical_cast*
- `bcp --boost=C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\boost_1_49_0 noncopyable static_assert ratio thread/locks thread chrono interprocess/mapped_region thread/recursive_mutex crc cstdint interprocess/file_mapping    make_shared shared_ptr lexical_cast lexical_cast ./myboost`
- copy *./myboost* into solution, set up properties, everything works fine until I'm not trying to #include "boost/chrono.hpp" (e.g. #include "boost/lexical_cast.hpp" is ok).
- boost/chrono.hpp causes linker error:

  3>playerMain.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::system_category(void)" (?system_category@system@boost@@YAABVerror_category@12@XZ)

  3>playerMain.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::generic_category(void)" (?generic_category@system@boost@@YAABVerror_category@12@XZ)

Do I use bcp correctly?
What should I do to make it work?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Boost is used on several platforms (Windows, Mac, Linux), so it's important that you specify what platform and compiler you're using before asking for help with installation. I had to deduce that you're using Visual Studio by spotting `msvc-10` in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process for installing Boost for use with Visual Studio is spelled out fairly clearly [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/more/getting_started/windows.html). You shouldn't need to write any installation scripts.

It's important to know that most Boost libraries are header-only (such as Boost.Lexical_Cast), yet some require you to link to a static library (such as Boost.System). See this [section](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#link-from-within-the-visual-studio-ide) of the Getting Started document on how to let Visual Studio know where the Boost static libraries are.

This [section](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#header-only-libraries) lists which libraries are **not** header-only. Some libraries (such as Boost.Chrono and Boost.Asio) are themselves header-only, but they depend on `Boost.System` which needs to be linked into your program.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Chrono isn't mentioned in this [section](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#header-only-libraries).

In [chrono doumentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/chrono/reference.html#chrono.reference.cpp0x.chrono_hpp.conf.header_only) there is a way to use chrono as header only.

I'm still fighting with that issue.

Comment: Problem solved. You were right, I had to add boost/stage/lib to VC++ Directories. Thanks.